# Working on a face recog project(using face_recognition) but when i am running the program to get face encodings it is showing list index out of range

Tags: python, list

```
    for file in os.listdir(dataset_dir):
    img = read_img(dataset_dir + '/' + file)
    img_enc = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
    dataset_encodings.append(img_enc)
    dataset_names.append(file.split('.')[0])
```

---> 17     img_enc = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]

IndexError: list index out of range.
I am not understanding why this problem is occuring. if anyone could guide me

Comment: please fix the code indentation and paste the error trace log.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `face_recognition.face_encodings(img)` will be returning an empty list (`[]`) so when you attempt to get the first element from it at index `0` it will raise an `IndexError` because there isn't a first element to retrieve.

```
>>> a = []                                                                                                                                
>>> a[0]                                                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                          
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                     
IndexError: list index out of range
```